# AEM 6.5 | New Features

Tags: cloud, content-management-system, aem

Can We list good AEM 6.5 features to developer to learn?

**Few Features i am aware**

-> AEM cloud
-> Sightly new tags added.

Can you inform me few more features.Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have look at the release notes here:
https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/release-notes/release-notes.html